# Trying to default rails time_select to blank values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

Ride is a model that has an attribute called :requested_time which is a datetime.  I want site users to be able to pick their time but not the date. I am trying to make a time select dropdown that defaults to a blank value.  A blank value is appearing in the form, but it is defaulting to 5AM and I am not sure why.  I want the default to be blank.  Here is the view code:

```
<%= f.time_select :requested_time, 
    {twelve_hour: true, minute_step: 15, ampm: true, include_blank: true},
     class: 'form-control pull-left', style: 'width: 10%; margin-right: 10px;' %>
```

What can I put in the view code to make the field default to blank values?

To illustrate my problem, here is what shows up:

[image]

If I click on the field, a blank value is there:

[image]

I want that blank value to be what the select field is automatically set to when the page load.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in the controller you have to some explicit checks like this:

```
if params[:start_time] && ! params[:start_time][:hour].blank? && !params[:start_time][:minute].blank?
  params[:event][:start_time] = "#{params[:start_time][:hour]}:#{params[:start_time][:minute]}:00"
else
  params[:event][:start_time] = nil
end
```

To confirm check to make sure that the browser is sending blanks up as the start_time, if it is then the above should work.

BTW the reason you are getting 5AM I am pretty sure is because of time zone issues.  Use Time.zone to set your zone properly.

Comment: Thanks but there is no params hash here?  This would only be involved in the create action, but I'm still in new.  Im not trying to change how its saved, but rather how it's viewed in the form.

Comment: sorry I am a little confused by "a blank value is appearing in the form, but it is defaulting to 5AM".  You see a blank on the form right?  And then when / where / how do you see the value 5AM?

Comment: I added some pictures to the question to make the problem easier to understand.

Comment: but underneath the select it does show a blank??? just confirming, and sorry to be thick!  My fault not yours :-)

Comment: No problem!  Yes, it shows it underneath the select.  The blank value is there but it's not defaulting to it.